# How to find out all permutations of numbers that sum to 100

Tags: c#, performance, linq, recursion, readability

I am trying to figure out an efficient way to create a method that takes a dictionary containing several lists of sequential integers (each list must start above 0 or higher and end on 100 or lower, but the exact numbers may vary) and returns a list of dictionaries containing all the permutations where the sum of all numbers amount to 100.

E.g., for 4 categories: 10 + 20 + 10 + 60 = 100

Each dictionary in the resulting list should store with a single integer value for each key.

Here's some code I came up with to illustrate my question:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace recursiveTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<int>> data = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
            data.Add("A", Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList());
            data.Add("B", Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList());
            data.Add("C", Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList());
            data.Add("D", Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList());
            // I would like to add a few entries more...

            List<Dictionary<string, int>> permutations = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();

            foreach (var a in data["A"])
            {
                foreach (var b in data["B"])
                {
                    foreach (var c in data["C"])
                    {
                        foreach (var d in data["D"])
                        {
                            if (a + b + c + d == 100)
                            {
                                var current = new Dictionary<string, int>()
                                {
                                    ["A"] = a,
                                    ["B"] = b,
                                    ["C"] = c,
                                    ["D"] = d,
                                };
                                permutations.Add(current);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Found (foreach): {permutations.Count()}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative using LINQ:

```cs
            List<Dictionary<string, int>> permutations2 = (from a in data["A"]
                                                           from b in data["B"]
                                                           from c in data["C"]
                                                           from d in data["D"]
                                                           where a + b + c + d == 100
                                                           let current = new Dictionary<string, int>()
                                                           {
                                                               ["A"] = a,
                                                               ["B"] = b,
                                                               ["C"] = c,
                                                               ["D"] = d,
                                                           }
                                                           select current).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine($"Found (LINQ): {permutations2.Count()}");
            Console.ReadKey();
```

It was not a very complicated task before the number of categories (dictionary keys) and numbers started to grow... Since the number of dictionary keys (categories) may vary, this seems to be a potential candidate for recursion, but I wasn't able to make it work. These two versions have a few obvious drawbacks:

1. As soon as the number of items and/or categories increases, suddenly the performance degrades.
2. Arrow shaped code seems like a recipe for disaster.
3. It tries to traverse all the possible combinations, while in fact just a few are useful (those that sum to 100).

What is the best way to achieve the intended result, with short and readable code and good performance?

Is there a way to filter out unnecessary loops while trying to find out those 100 sum values?

---

**EDIT:**
For clarification, My idea is to be able to define a method with a signature like this:

```cs
private static List<Dictionary<string, int>> GetValidPermutations(Dictionary<string, List<int>> data)
```

Then call it like this:

```cs
List<Dictionary<string, int>> permutations = GetValidPermutations(data);
```

Comment: So you want to take exactly one number from each list for the sum, is that correct?

Comment: Right. It takes a list for each category, so the input is a dictionary of string keys (categories) and List<int> values. The method should return a list of dictionaries each of these dictionaries should have the same set of keys (categories) and a single int value for each of those. The sum of the values for each dictionary in this output list should always be 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enhance performance, the key is to reduce the number of unnecessary iterations:

```
static List<Dictionary<string, int>> GetValidPermutations(int target, Dictionary<string, List<int>> data)
{
    return GetValidPermutations(target, data, 0, new int[data.Count])
            .Select(perm => CreateDictionary(data.Keys, perm))
            .ToList();
}

static Dictionary<string, int> CreateDictionary(IEnumerable<string> keys, IEnumerable<int> values)
{
    return keys.Zip(values, KeyValuePair.Create)
               .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
}

static IEnumerable<int[]> GetValidPermutations(int target, Dictionary<string, List<int>> data, int level, int[] sequence)
{
    if (level < sequence.Length)
    {
        var currentList = data.ElementAt(level).Value;
        var subsequentLists = data.Skip(level + 1).Select(x => x.Value);
        int start = Math.Max(currentList[0], target - subsequentLists.Sum(x => x.Last()));
        int end = Math.Min(currentList.Last(), target - subsequentLists.Sum(x => x[0]));
        for (sequence[level] = start; sequence[level] <= end; sequence[level]++)
        {
            int subTarget = target - sequence[level];
            foreach (var perm in GetValidPermutations(subTarget, data, level + 1, sequence))
            {
                yield return perm;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var perm = sequence.Append(target);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(perm.Sum() == 100);
        yield return perm.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The `start` and `end` above is carefully calculated to include the necessary iterations only. Other values are skipped because they cannot form the permutation.

Then you can call the method like this:

```
var p4 = GetValidPermutations(100, data);
Console.WriteLine($"Found (Recursion): {p4.Count()}");
```

It may be difficult to understand the recursion version in the first place, there is the for loop equivalent, you can see that some code sections are repeated:

```
const int TARGET = 100;
var permutations3 = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();

int aStart = Math.Max(data["A"][0], TARGET - data["B"].Last() - data["C"].Last() - data["D"].Last());
int aEnd = Math.Min(data["A"].Last(), TARGET - data["B"][0] - data["C"][0] - data["D"][0]);
for (int a = aStart; a <= aEnd; a++)
{
    int bStart = Math.Max(data["B"][0], TARGET - a - data["C"].Last() - data["D"].Last());
    int bEnd = Math.Min(data["B"].Last(), TARGET - a - data["C"][0] - data["D"][0]);
    for (int b = bStart; b <= bEnd; b++)
    {
        int cStart = Math.Max(data["C"][0], TARGET - a - b - data["D"].Last());
        int cEnd = Math.Min(data["C"].Last(), TARGET - a - b - data["D"][0]);
        for (int c = cStart; c <= cEnd; c++)
        {
            var perm = new Dictionary<string, int>
            {
                { "A", a },
                { "B", b },
                { "C", c },
                { "D", TARGET - a - b - c }
            };
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(perm["D"] >= data["D"][0] && perm["D"] <= data["D"].Last());
            permutations3.Add(perm);
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine($"Found (for): {permutations3.Count()}");
```

The skipping logic can be illustrated by the following examples:

Suppose the maximum values of B, C, D are 10, 20, 30 respectively, then A needs to be at least 40 to have a sum of 100. Such that A can start from 40 and 0-39 are skipped (if available).

Similar logic can be applied to skipping higher ranges. Suppose the minimum values of B, C, D are 5, 10, 15 respectively, then A cannot exceed 70. Because the sum will exceed 100 if so. So we can stop looping when A exceeds 70.

Applying the skipping logic for all categories can result in the above code. In addition, the last category can be directly calculated without looping.

Comment: Its seems to be a good approximation to what I intended, and it really improved on performance. However, this solution does not allow each of the categories do have variable start/end values, it just assumes 1-100. My intention is to allow, for each category, a start value that may be 0 or higher and an end value that may be 100 or lower. Can it be modified to accept the provided Dictionary (`data`) as input argument to the recursive method?

Comment: @VictorDomingos Yes, you can view the updated version.

Comment: On the first method, I get a syntax error on `return GetValidPermutations(target, data, 0, new int[data.Count])
        .Select(perm => data.Keys.Zip(perm, KeyValuePair.Create)
                                 .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value))
        .ToList(); ` where `KeyValuePair.Create` seems not to be found. What is the intended result of this part?

Comment: @VictorDomingos That part is used to form the dictionary format output as the recursive method returns int array. `data.Keys.Zip(perm, KeyValuePair.Create)` will return `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` then be converted to dictionary.

Comment: @VictorDomingos Code revised for clarity.

Comment: Maybe it's something with my VS installation. As soon as `using System.Linq`is added to the source code, Intellisense highlights `Create` with an error ('KeyValuePair' does not contain a definition for 'Create'). I replaced that with a slightly more verbose `(k, v) => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(k, v)` which seems to do the same.